# Get JSON element using SQL without specifying record index?

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have JSON data in this format:

```
[{"DocumentFormStatus":"Submitted","DocumentType":"DocType1"},{"DocumentFormStatus":"Submitted","DocumentType":"DocType2"},{"DocumentFormStatus":"Submitted","DocumentType":"DocType3"},{"DocumentFormStatus":"Submitted","DocumentType":"DocType4"}]
```

I would like to be able to get the data in tabular format like so:

| DocumentFormStatus | DocumentType |
| --- | --- |
| Submitted | DocType1 |
| Submitted | DocType2 |
| Submitted | DocType3 |
| Submitted | DocType4 |

I am able to pull the data like below however, this is obviously limited to the element index specified (I have to run multiple instances of this query and do a UNION between them all). How can I get all records in a JSON element without specifying the record index?

```
SELECT
    DocumentSubmissionStatus = JSON_VALUE(LWDocs.DMDetails, '$[0].DocumentFormStatus'),
    DocumentType = JSON_VALUE(LWDocs.DMDetails, '$[0].DocumentType')
FROM OPENROWSET(
    'CosmosDB', N'account=...;database=...;region=...;key=...',cDB
) AS LWDocs
```

Comment: `... AS LWDocs CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(LWDocs.DMDetails)`, then `JSON_VALUE` on the `value`.

Answer (score 1):

you can use OPENJSON

```
declare @Json nvarchar(max)='
[{"DocumentFormStatus":"Submitted","DocumentType":"DocType1"}
,{"DocumentFormStatus":"Submitted","DocumentType":"DocType2"}
,{"DocumentFormStatus":"Submitted","DocumentType":"DocType3"}
,{"DocumentFormStatus":"Submitted","DocumentType":"DocType4"}]
'



SELECT  
         DocumentFormStatus,DocumentType
   

    FROM
    OPENJSON(@json)
    WITH
    (
            DocumentFormStatus varchar(100) N'$.DocumentFormStatus'
            ,DocumentType varchar(100) N'$.DocumentType' 
       

        
) AS a
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems your JSON is in a table.  Use a CROSS APPLY

**Example**

```
Declare @Yourtable table (id int,DMDetails varchar(max))
Insert Into @Yourtable values 
(1, '[{"DocumentFormStatus":"Submitted","DocumentType":"DocType1"},{"DocumentFormStatus":"Submitted","DocumentType":"DocType2"},{"DocumentFormStatus":"Submitted","DocumentType":"DocType3"},{"DocumentFormStatus":"Submitted","DocumentType":"DocType4"}]')

Select A.ID
      ,B.*
 From  @Yourtable A
 Cross Apply OpenJSON(DMDetails)
     with ( DocumentFormStatus  varchar(150)
           ,DocumentType        varchar(150)
          )  B
```

**Results**

```
ID  DocumentFormStatus  DocumentType
1   Submitted           DocType1
1   Submitted           DocType2
1   Submitted           DocType3
1   Submitted           DocType4
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an other way to do it using `JSON_VALUE` and `OPENJSON`

```
SELECT JSON_VALUE ( j.value , '$.DocumentFormStatus' ) as DocumentFormStatus,
       JSON_VALUE ( j.value , '$.DocumentType' ) as DocumentType
FROM LWDocs
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(LWDocs.DMDetails) as j
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/QkoL0SVX)